# Python dict keyerror in while statement (.get() works)

Tags: python, dictionary, keyerror

In a class I have a nested dict

```
tree = {"left":tree_left,"right":tree_right,"class":class,"split":split}
```

where `tree_left,tree_right` also are dictionaries on the same form.

If I write

```py
 tree = self.tree
 while tree["split"]:
          do stuff
```

it throws the `KeyError: "split"` but writing

```py
 tree = self.tree
 while tree.get("split"):
          do stuff
```

it works. I have furthermore tried

```py
 tree = self.tree
 print(tree["split"])
 while tree["split"]:
          do stuff
```

which prints the correct value and then throws the error.

Any reason why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When *tree* doesn't have *split* key, `tree["split"]` will throw `KeyError` exception while `tree.get("split")` will return `None` and the code will exit the while loop without any exception (the loop condition will be logically `False`).

Another way to check if *split* exists in your *tree* variable would be:

```
while "split" in tree:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: I actually just thought that either of the syntax was from an older version of python which have not been removed (i.e dict.get(key) was the original and then dict[key] came) but returned the same. Thanks a bunch

Comment: btw `get()` allows you to return default value if the key doesn't exist - `dict.get(key, default_value)`. If the second param is not provided, `None` will be the default value.